# There is no bump in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

For some reason, the bump of bread only works in eevee, in cycles only displacment works. In other projects displacment works normally. I use procedural texture

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: @Sanbaldo I attached a photo to the publication. All material is very big, but in generally there is some superimposed textures, then I guide black and white factor in mixing colors and input height in displacement node, then displacement node into displacement material output

Comment: you can try using the NORMAL node inside the "principled BSDF". you should connect there a BUMP node.

Comment: @Sanbaldo if I use setting "Bump only" effect becomes like Eevee, may be I have not enough faces. Also In Cycles lighning is not such beautiul. Probably I should use only bump effect

Answer (score 2):

I think it goes like this:

If you set the Cycles settings of a material to 'Displacement' only, then EEVEE, not supporting Displacement shading,  will substitute Bump mapping for any Displacement input to the Material Output node, to make the Cycles and EEVEE renders to look as similar as possible.

Cycles can't depend on that substitution - if you want a normal or bump-map in Cycles, you have to ask for one explicitly:

[image]

Not necessarily in Object space, but you get the idea..